# Using operators on properties in Python

Tags: python, properties, python-3.x, operators

Using Python 3.2.3 at the moment:

I am consistently running into a problem when using properties in Python. I don't know if my problem is due to the way properties work in Python (I come from the C++/Delphi/C# world) or something I'm doing incorrectly:

**Examples:**

*Definition:*

```
    class MyClass(object):

            ...

      self.__stringProp = "Mikey"

      @property
      def StringProp(self):
        return self.__stringProp
```

*Usage:*

```
p  = "Python"
m = p + MyClass.StringProp
```

*Error:*

```
Unsupported operand type(p) for +: 'property' and 'str'
```

Same in many similar cases - cannot use operators for a type on a property of that type, or if I expose an instance of a class as a property, I cannot access the callables in the class because it is accessed as a property.

Am I doing something wrong, or do Python's properties behave differently than the typed data they represent, unlike other languages I am familiar with?

Comment: Why are you accessing the property on the class instead of on an instance?  The property is only an interface to data stored on an instance; if you access it on the class there is no data to return.  Also, your class code is invalid as you are using `self` outside of a method.

Comment: How about: `m = p + myInstanceOfClass.StringProp`?

Comment: @BrenBarn - ' your class code is invalid '. No - that's why the '...' is there - it means etc - 'blah blah blah'.

Comment: @Mikey Neither `...` nor `blah blah blah` are a legitimate part of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I've seen '...' used in many examples for many years. First time I encountered someone who didn't get it. BTW, has SSCCE been passed into law? Compilable? Ridiculous IMO. You need to put enough to make the problem understandable - that's sufficient.

Comment: @Mikey: Regardless of the ..., the problem is that your use of `self` (even based on its indentation alone) is not inside a method.

Comment: @BrenBarn - I did get a quick answer to my question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties only work on **instances** of a class. You are accessing the property object itself, directly, on the class:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'Hello world!'
... 
>>> Foo.bar
<property object at 0x101455f70>
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
'Hello world!'
```

Here `Foo` is a class, `foo` is an instance of that class.

Use properties *only* when you need to either make the attribute read-only, or when you need to run code to either get or set the values. Don't just use attributes like you would in Java, there is no need to do so in Python. Python [is *not* Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

In Java, you have to use getters and setters because you cannot change your mind and change the public fields to getters and setters later on. In python, you can, so don't use getters and setters until you have an actual need to.

If you want to know the full ins and outs of how Python properties work, read the [Python Descriptor HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html); the `property` object is a descriptor, as are methods on Python classes; through the magic of `__get__` and `__set__` methods they transform attribute access on instances.

Comment: Yup. Duh moment for me :-). I use read only properties in Python in places where I would use statics or named constants in other languages and an instance is not necessary.

Comment: Python Descriptor HOWTO - good reference. Thanks. Python is deceptively simple to use, but there is a great deal of depth in it that can make it very flexible and interesting. I use Beazley's Essential Reference a great deal - he goes into everything. Best Python book out there IMO.